# How to create multiple instances of the same singleton service in .NET Core?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, singleton

Supposing that I have 10 Machines that they have instruments attached to them and different users could access a machine, but not all users have access to all the machines.
So, I have a `IMachineInstrumentService` abstraction and a `MachineInstrumentService` implementation.

How I should create 10 Singleton instances of a `IMachineInstrumentService` in startUp.cs?
Is this possible or should I create a scoped `IMachineInstrumentService` and to create 10 mutexes for the machines

For example something like this

```cs
foreach(var machine in Machines)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IMachineInstrumentService , MachineInstrumentService >(machine); 
}
```

Comment: Did you test your sample code? Is it not working for you, and if so, why doesn't this solve your problem?

Comment: Are you looking for 10 different singletons, or the same singleton used across 10 different machines?

Comment: I want 10 singletons of the same type . One for each machine.